# how to add session cart table in database and give all ordered items one unique orderid?

Tags: c#

```
ProductName     price   brand   Quantity    Net   AmountNet   Amount    Update
```

I have the above table in which I have to insert the products which users have added to their cart.
Users can add multiple products to their cart.
I have that table of user added products in the session and I am reading it row by row by taking that session table as a datatable.
I have to insert all products row by row in above table.

I also have another table as follows:

```
orderID    CartItemID   RegistrationID   OrderDate   NetAmount  Remarks   Created
```

My question is, how to give one unique order id to all products ordered by a user?

Answer (score 0):

In my project I use 3 tables, to solve this problem

```
CREATE TABLE cart(
    ID          NUMBER,
    CUSTOMER_ID NUMBER,
    DATE        DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE,
    SESSION_ID  VARCHAR2(32 BYTE)
)

CREATE TABLE cart_parameter(
    SESSION_ID  VARCHAR2(32 BYTE),
    CODE        VARCHAR2(32 BYTE),
    TYPE        VARCHAR2(32 BYTE),
    AMOUNT      NUMBER
)

CREATE TABLE product(
    ID          NUMBER,
    CODE        VARCHAR2(32 BYTE),
    description VARCHAR2(200 BYTE),
    price       NUMBER(30,2),
    ... more info
)

Other tables
```

This architecture is correct so that the basket can be a different number of items, and in different tables. for example you have a table with computers, smart phones, books, and so on. At your option you put the product ID, but different tables can be different products with the same identifier. Then you have a problem with the expansion of applications

This function returns a unique value for this session

```
FUNCTION getSessionID
IS

BEGIN
 RETURN utl_raw.cast_to_raw(DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT.MD5(TO_CHAR(customer_id) || TO_CHAR(systimestamp, 'DDMONYYYYHH24MISSFF') || s_user_ip || dbms_random.random()));
END;
```

Use this sessionID for connect the cart table and cart_parameter table

P/S: Forgive me for my English, it's all google translate

Comment: sir,
but how to use that fn and how to get session id?

Comment: This code is suitable for Oracle.but the logic is clear, take the user ID, the system date, ip user, and a random number

Comment: This function return = "B4F96DFDF9CDE05F57C485D2A4DF53FF"

Comment: sir i m not exact getting your suggestion.
will you please guid me any other way.

Comment: at the time of authentication you are using some sort of a unique hash code?